# uitabbarcontroller -jump between to uiviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have uitabbarcontroller with two uiviewcontroller.

i want to know if there is possibility that i will add a button  in the first viewcontroller that when he pressed the app will jump to the second uiviewcontroller in the uitabbarcontroller.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the selectedIndex property for UITabBarController.